# Can I log in if I browse with Tor? Is it safe?

Tags: browsers

If I browse with Tor, can I log in to my gmail, skydrive, etc. account?
Doesn'T google, microsoft etc know then its me?

I don't get that, thank you for explaining this to me.

Comment: That's not the point of Tor. Tor is primarily designed to hide your online activities from your own ISP or government.

Answer (score 2):

If you log in to any of these account you lose your anonymity. If you log in to any account, you are telling them who you are. Tor can not protect your anonymity if you are advertising who you are to the world. You can log in, but you are no longer anonymous. If you log in, the only thing Tor can do for you is to hide where you are located at, but if you tell them even where you are located at somehow, then Tor can not do anything for you. Remember first you have to do something for yourself (for example not logging in)  before you can ask Tor to do something for you.

Answer (score 1):

What Roya said, indeed!

However, you can create new accounts, using pseudonyms. But if you do, you must avoid creating associations to your true name. Just using the Tor browser is weak. Better is using Tails or Whonix, to reduce the risk of cross contamination through exploits. You can have as many pseudonyms as you like, but don't mix them in one Tails session. Each could have its own Whonix instance.